# How to specify portable data source in web.xml or elsewhere in Arquillian?

Tags: jakarta-ee, datasource, web.xml, jboss-arquillian

I'm getting started with Arquillian and noticed that one has to specify data sources to be used with JTA in JPA in the server specific files (`jboss-ds.xml`, `glassfish-resources.xml`, etc.), however in Java EE > 6 it should be possible to specify it in `web.xml` (or `ejb-jar.xml`, `application.xml` or `application-client.xml`), e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    [...]
    <data-source>
        <name>jdbc/project1</name>
        <class-name>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource</class-name>
        <server-name>localhost</server-name>
        <database-name>project1</database-name>
        <user>project1</user>
        <password>project1</password>
        <property>
            <name>connectionAttributes</name>
            <value>create=true</value>
        </property>
        <transactional>true</transactional>
        <isolation-level>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</isolation-level>
        <initial-pool-size>2</initial-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-statements>0</max-statements>
    </data-source>
</web-app>
```

and use it as follows:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    WebArchive retValue = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClasses(MyManagedBean.class, SaveController.class, DefaultSaveController.class)
            .setWebXML("web.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    Stream.of(Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class)).forEach(archive -> retValue.addAsLibrary(archive));
    return retValue;
}
```

which would avoid redundancies. However the data source isn't available, e.g GlassFish fails due to `Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/project1__pm`.

Arquillian seems to create a data source which might be usable, but I'd like to test the exact type of my production environment since those tests are very close to integration already.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to follow [Arquillian JPA tutorial](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/) and use the `glassfish-resourcess.xml`.If you follow  you would see the following file structures of the maven project.

[image]

once you have this package and file structures then  point your test resources to `pom.xml`by adding `<testResources>` tag.

`pom.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>project-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
   <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>infohub-entities</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>project-service</name>
    
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then in `glassfish-resources.xml` you can create your portable data-source configuration.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/datasource" object-type="user" pool-name="connectionPool">
    <description/>
  </jdbc-resource>
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false"
                    associate-with-thread="false"
                    connection-creation-retry-attempts="0"
                    connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10"
                    connection-leak-reclaim="false"
                    connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0"
                    connection-validation-method="auto-commit"
                    datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
                    fail-all-connections="false"
                    idle-timeout-in-seconds="300"
                    is-connection-validation-required="false"
                    is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true"
                    lazy-connection-association="false"
                    lazy-connection-enlistment="false"
                    match-connections="false"
                    max-connection-usage-count="0"
                    max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000"
                    name="connectionPool"
                    non-transactional-connections="false"
                    pool-resize-quantity="2"
                    res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                    statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1"
                    steady-pool-size="8"
                    validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0"
                    wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//url:port"/>
    <property name="User" value="username"/>
    <property name="Password" value="password"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

And point the data-source in `arquillian.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="glassfish-embedded" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="resourcesXml">
                src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

so your data-source is portable which will be available to each time test start.
For complete solution follow [Arquillian JPA Tutorial](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/). or  [Arquillian Blog](http://arquillian.org/blog/2010/10/04/the-perfect-recipe-for-testing-jpa-2-revisited/)

Answer (score 0):

name should be "java:app/jdbc/project1" or "java:global/jdbc/project1"